# Is it safe to emit signal from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety, qt-signals

Is it safe to emit a signal on an object from another thread (if the slot is connected as `QueuedConnection`)? I couldn't find a specific piece of documentation that would mention this, the most [relevant quote](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html) I found is this:

> QObject is reentrant. Most of its non-GUI subclasses, such as QTimer,
>   QTcpSocket, QUdpSocket and QProcess, are also reentrant, making it
>   possible to use these classes from multiple threads simultaneously.
>   Note that these classes are designed to be created and used from
>   within a single thread; **creating an object in one thread and calling
>   its functions from another thread is not guaranteed to work**.

This suggest that it might not be OK, does this also apply to signals? There is a `QMutexLocker` inside `QMetaObject::activate`, so it looks to me that it might be thread safe...?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Foo(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {}

public slots:
    void run()
    {
        connect(this, &Foo::signal, this, [] { std::cout << "activated"; }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

        std::thread t([this] { emit signal(); });
        if (t.joinable()) t.join();
    }

signals:
    void signal() const;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Foo* b = new Foo(&a);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, b, &Foo::run);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: How about Qt's documentation on [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads)?

Comment: @AMA: it only mentions the situation when sender and receiver live in a different thread, but that's a different problem... I'm asking about invoking a signal from a thread that the object doesn't live in.

Comment: @Jaa-c it doesn't matter, where object lives. It is safe to emit signals from another thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Qt is based on queues of events. Each Qt thread has its own queue and associated event loop around it. So when you have a situation where 2 different objects are living it 2 different threads and one is connected to another through the signals/slots mechanism (either by Auto or Queued connection) the following happens during the emission: the code inside the signal creates an event and posts it to the queue of the object-receiver. The receiver's event loop is running through the queue, finds the event posted and executes an appropriate slot.

The queue is guaranteed to be thread safe so it is absolutely safe to emit signals across threads. The quote in your questions talks about the situation where you make a *direct call* on the object living in `T1` from `T2`.

There is a great article about threads, qobjects, signals, slots and how everything relates to each other: [Threads Events QObjects](http://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects). I recommend to read it if you want to understand it deeper.

---

Regarding the code in question. You have a queued connection and it means that it doesn't matter if the sender and receiver live in one thread or different ones. It doesn't matter if the sender and receiver are 2 objects or the same. The said routine will be the same. If you created an Auto connection then it would have a Direct call but you didn't. And a relevant quote from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html):

> On the other hand, you can safely emit signals from your
>   QThread::run() implementation, **because signal emission is thread-safe**.

Comment: But I am making a direct call from another thread. In my example, that is `emit this->signal()`. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Jaa-c, no you aren't. You are making a queued call.

Comment: The slot is called from an event queue, yes. But the signal itself is a direct call of a function.

Comment: @Jaa-c, signal *is not* a function, not in Qt vocabulary. Signal is a C++ function but in terms of Qt calling a C++ signal function means _emitting a signal_. These are 2 different notions.

Comment: @Jaa-c To re-iterate, the signal method is a C++ function, which is generated by *moc* (you can check the moc-generated .cpp file to see what it has in it). And per documentation, calling this method (AKA emitting the signal) is thread safe. Now if you have explicitly direct connections between threads, *then* you have to make also the slot thread safe (but don't abuse the signal/slot system like this, because it is so very easy to mess up).

Comment: Signals are sort-of weird indeed. A signal acts as-if it was a call to all of the directly connected slots, in connection order. It also acts as-if it was injection of all effectively queued-connected slots into their objects' threads, with the threads being - at the time of the call - in a state where it is relatively safe to do so. That's the mental picture I have - there isn't really a one true picture here, and as long as it helps in understanding and isn't based on false premises nor leads to false conclusions, it's "good". Thus: just my 0.2E-1 currency units.

Answer (score 2):

yes it's the prefered way because qt GUI prevents change a thread directly from another thread
so you should emit a signal from the thread one and connect it (receive it) in the thread tow and depends on signal type execute some of your thread code
if you tried to execute code directly you will get this error

> QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread