# QObject singleton living on main thread, invoke it's signal from another thread, is it thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread, qt-signals, qobject

as the title says,
I have a `Core` singleton that inherits from `QObject` that is constructed on the main thread.
I also Have a `QTcpServer` that is creating a new `QThread` for each new connection, that is where I serve Http Requests.
sometimes I need to invoke a signal called `newMessage(...)` that belongs to the `Core` singleton from an Http request handler thread, the purpose is to notify a `QWebSocket` server living on the main thread to propagate the event to the connected websockets.

so it's like

```
HttpResponse HttpController::callback(HttpRequest *request){
//a callback of an object living inside a handler thread
//some code
emit Core::instance()->newMessage(...) //this object is living on the main thread
//do some work
//return HttpResponse(...)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to emit signal from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219114/is-it-safe-to-emit-signal-from-another-thread)

Comment: Conclusion: Yes, signal emission is thread safe. Note that `Core::instance()` should be thread safe too.

Comment: I believe you want to connect the any slot for this signal with Qt::QueuedConnection if it is not already using that.

Comment: yes, it is thread safe, I'm using Qt::QueuedConnection and Core::instance() returns a pointer to the static pointer.